# MATLAB maximum variable size exceeded during 2-way ANOVA

Tags: matlab, variables, size, anova

I am trying to run a 2-way random effects ANOVA on a set of data in MATLAB. This is the code I am using:

```
[pval table stats terms] = anovan(modelfit, {RATEES RATERS},...
 'model', 'interaction', 'random', 2, 'varnames', {'RATEE' 'RATER'})
```

However, doing this gives me the error:

```
??? Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.

Error in ==> termcross at 13
ab = a(:,acols) .* b(:,bcols);

Error in ==> anovan>maketerm at 1470
         tdum = termcross(termdum{k}, tdum);

Error in ==> anovan>makedummyterms at 1122
   [tdum,vars,tn,df0,tconstr] = maketerm(tm,isnested,varinfo,j,sindex,...

Error in ==> anovan at 199
terminfo = makedummyterms(sindex, termlist, varinfo, ...
```

I know what this error means, but I don't really understand why I am getting it here. If I modify my code to any one of the following, it will work without error, but it isn't giving me the data I need:

```
[pval table stats terms] = anovan(modelfit, {RATEES RATERS},...
 'random', 2, 'varnames',     {'RATEE' 'RATER'})

[pval table stats terms] = anovan(modelfit, {RATEES RATERS})
```

It just doesn't work when I try to use the 'interaction' model. Why? Do I really just have too much data? The size of each of my input variable (modelfit, RATEES, RATERS) are all 14879 x 1. That is, 1 column arrays with 14879 values.

If this is really too much, how do I go about getting the interaction effects I need?

EDIT: In case it is relevant, I am using a 64-bit Mac OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard) and MATLAB R2008a.

EDIT2: I also don't understand how to use the 'random' element of the anovan command. I have to put in an index, but it only lets me choose a single variable to be a random effect? I want both RATEES and RATERS to be random, but it only lets me choose one! Why is MATLAB so inflexible for this type of analysis?